# Start YouTube playlist video at the beginning of video

Tags: youtube

My YouTube playlists don't start at the beginning of the video. This is frustrating for music; whenever a new video starts it starts at some point in the middle or near the end. This is the same problem that is described in this locked support ticket: [Videos on my playlist don’t start at the beginning](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/32339019/videos-on-my-playlist-don%E2%80%99t-start-at-the-beginning?hl=en).

Is there a way to configure YouTube to start videos in a playlist at the beginning?

I already tried clearing cookies.

Answer (score -2):

If you clear your watch history, it might reset the videos so they will start at the beginning.

Comment: _it might reset the videos_ It would probably have been more useful if you knew this for a fact, or had tested it yourself. As it stands, this is really a comment rather than an answer.